# Simplify the following transfer function

Tags: stochastic-processes

This question is related to Weiner filter. However my doubt is not about the Wiener Filter itself but the calculations from one of the exercise.

I was given:
$$H(f) = \frac{S_v(f)}{S_v(f)+S_x(f)}$$
where,
$$S_v(f)=(1-|f|)I_{[-1,1]}(f)$$
$$S_x(f)=1-I_{[-1,1]}(f)$$
Hence, I have:
$$H(f) = \frac{(1-|f|)I_{[-1,1]}(f)}{1-|f|I_{[-1,1]}(f)}$$
But the answer further simplifies it to:
$$H(f) = I_{[-1,1]}(f)$$

How do I achieve the last step? It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to show that

$$ \frac{(1-|f|)I_{[-1,1]}(f)}{1-|f|I_{[-1,1]}(f)} = I_{[-1,1]}(f). \tag{$\star$}$$

You can show this by cases. (Note that technically the LHS here is undefined if $f=\pm 1$ since you get $0/0$.)

**Case 1:** $-1<  f < 1$ (i.e. $|f|<1$)

In this case, the RHS of $(\star)$ is $1$ and the LHS is also $\frac{(1-|f|)\times 1}{1 -|f|\times 1} = \frac{1-|f|}{1-|f|}=1$.

**Case 2:** $|f| > 1$

In this case, the RHS is $0$ and the LHS is also $\frac{(1-|f|)\times 0}{1 -|f|\times 0} = \frac{0}{1}=0$.